# Row Won't Select - MVC 3

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an MVC 3 application in C# and I am trying to make a row in a table turn gray when "Select" next to the row is clicked. However, this is not happening.

Here is my code in the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Confirm", "Invoice"))
{

foreach (var item in Model)
{
    string selectedRow = "";
    if (item.InvoiceNumberID == ViewBag.InvoiceNumberID)
    {
        selectedRow = "selectedRow";
    } 

<tr class="@selectedRow" valign="top">
            <td> 
           <a href='javascript:void(0)' class='select' data-id=@item.InvoiceNumberID >Select</a>


        </td> 
     <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceNumberID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceAmount)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceMonth)
    </td>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.selectedRow 
{ 
background-color: #EEEEEE; 
}
```

The code from the example I tried to use for my project is below:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Instructors) 
{ 
    string selectedRow = ""; 
    if (item.PersonID == ViewBag.PersonID) 
    { 
        selectedRow = "selectedrow"; 
    } 
    <tr class="@selectedRow" valign="top"> 
        <td> 
            @Html.ActionLink("Select", "Index", new { id = item.PersonID }) | 
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.PersonID }) | 
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.PersonID }) | 
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.PersonID }) 
        </td> 
        <td> 
            @item.LastName 
        </td> 
        <td> 
            @item.FirstMidName 
        </td> 
        <td> 
            @String.Format("{0:d}", item.HireDate) 
        </td> 
        <td> 
            @if (item.OfficeAssignment != null) 
            { 
                @item.OfficeAssignment.Location  
            } 
        </td> 
        <td>
            @{
                foreach (var course in item.Courses)
                {
                    @course.CourseID @:&nbsp; @course.Title <br />
                }
            }
        </td>
    </tr> 
}
```

And from their controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(Int32? id, Int32? courseID)
    {
        var viewModel = new InstructorIndexData();
        viewModel.Instructors = db.Instructors
            .Include(i => i.Courses.Select(c => c.Department))
            .OrderBy(i => i.LastName);

        if (id != null)
        {
            ViewBag.PersonID = id.Value;
            viewModel.Courses = viewModel.Instructors.Where(i => i.PersonID == id.Value).Single().Courses;
        }


        if (courseID != null)
        {
            ViewBag.CourseID = courseID.Value;

            var selectedCourse = viewModel.Courses.Where(x => x.CourseID == courseID).Single();
            db.Entry(selectedCourse).Collection(x => x.Enrollments).Load();
            foreach (Enrollment enrollment in selectedCourse.Enrollments)
            {
                db.Entry(enrollment).Reference(x => x.Student).Load();
            }

            viewModel.Enrollments = viewModel.Courses.Where(x => x.CourseID == courseID).Single().Enrollments;
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

The intention is different though - all I want to see is make the row change colour - with the example I used, they wanted related data to display, which I don't need.

Thanks,
Amy

Comment: Is there a row in your final HTML that looks like this `<tr class="selectedRow" valign="top">`?

Comment: What do you mean by final HTML? When the page is rendered?

Comment: I mean by what you see in your web browser when you look at the source code.

Comment: so why do you expect that your CSS class rule will be applied? It applies only to elements that have `class="selectedRow"`. If you don't have such row in your markup you cannot expect much to happen. So you will need to fix your markup first.

Comment: But the row is only supposed to have the class once it's selected, not so? So when I load the page, it shouldn't be there in the source code? But when I press Select, the row doesn't take on that class.

Comment: I don't know, did you write some code that will handle the click on this Select button?

Comment: Well, it should be this:         string selectedRow = "";
        if (item.InvoiceNumberID == ViewBag.InvoiceNumberID)
        {
            selectedRow = "selectedRow";
        }. But it's probably because there is some code is missing from the controller to do with viewbags

Comment: that's server side code, not javascript. You seem to be confusion those 2 notions. To achieve what you are asking here you need javascript which runs on the client.

Comment: I only added the javascript later to retrieve the value of the ID. It is unrelated to the CSS. Everything I want the javascript to do is working

Comment: Well, if you don't have the required CSS class on your `tr` I wouldn't exactly call it `working` but you wish...

Comment: I'm not trying to add the class with the javascript. The class I'm trying to add is selectedRow, not the 'select' in the JS

Comment: If you are not trying to add the class with javascript then probably your `if (item.InvoiceNumberID == ViewBag.InvoiceNumberID)` condition is wrong?

Comment: Yes, that's where I think the problem is. Because that's the only place where I mention the viewbag because I don't know how to write the code for it. In the example I used, they had this: 
            if (id != null)
            {
                ViewBag.PersonID = id.Value;
                viewModel.Courses = viewModel.Instructors.Where(i => i.PersonID == id.Value).Single().Courses;
            }. But I couldn't get it to adapt to my solution properly

Comment: Do you realize that from the information you provided in your question it is impossible to get answers? I mean you only showed a small portion of your view code. There is much more tat you will need to show. Things like how your view models look like, your controller actions and your full views. Once we have tat information we might be able to help you. Right now we need some magic crystal ball to guess how your code looks like. So please update your question and provide all relevant information. And don't use the comments section to post code samples. Their are totally unreadable.

Comment: Sorry, this was the only code I knew to be relevant - I didn't have any code in my controller. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Think about it. How would your server code get executed when you click the checkbox. Without some javascript to cause a postback, your server side code know what checkbox is selected. However, that's probably not the best way to handle it. Your client-side javascript should do the adding of the class.

You seem to not understand the difference between server side and client side functionality, perhaps learning a bit about what happens when you click the checkbox might be in order.

Comment: The javascript code works 100% fine - I'm using that to retrieve the value, not change the style. It's just the @selectedRow that isn't working. I got the code for that from a working example. But in the example, they had code related to ViewBag in the controller, which I don't but I'm not sure how to write it

Comment: @Amy - you're not quite getting it.  When you click the checkbox, nothing happens because the checkbox is not wired up to do anything.  You either have to make it post back, or make the javascript set the style to selected.  Otherwise nothing will happen.  The only way to change the row color is to do some action, and you aren't doing that (at least you haven't show you are)

Comment: The javascript has nothing to do with setting the style, I am trying to set the style with the @selectRow part and the ViewBag - the javascript is just there to get the ID, which works fine. I am just not sure how to code the ViewBag section in the controller to get the CSS to work

Comment: @Amy - You're not listening.  When you click the checkbox, nothing happens because checkboxes are just checkboxes.  They don't do anything by themselves.  Therefore, clicking on it will do nothing *UNLESS* you write some javascript to do something when you click it.  Without that, it will never do anything.  ViewBag is only available on the server, and you don't have access to anything ViewBag related on the client.

Comment: I am aware of that, I know it needs to post to the server. The working example I found though did not use any javascript to select the row. The link under "Select" however, linked back to the same page so that the page was refreshed. I will edit my post above to show the code they used. And this is the code I am trying to implement in my own.

Comment: @Amy - your example did not show anything about posting to the server, nor did your question mention it.  You simply said that when you clicked the checkbox nothing happened.  If you want help, you need to explicitly define your question, not assume we can read your mind.

Comment: I didn't show anything posting to the server because there isn't anything. It's an action link, not a checkbox, so maybe that's why? All I know is that when I run their code example, the row becomes gray when I press select. It's the example code from the MVC part of the official ASP.net site. The only HttpPost section in their code is for Edit and Create which is unrelated